# Flickering Text Problem using CSS Padding Hover Transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm not even sure if this is possible!

I'm trying to animate the padding amount around a centered text link. When you click on the text link, the padding is changed from 20% to 100% - this bit works :)

The text is centered using CSS

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

I'm using transition property to animate the padding bit

```
transition-property: padding;
transition-duration: .5s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
```

Apologies if the code is a little clunky - here's the full code I'm using here:

```css
#homePanel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#homePanel img {
  width: 100%;
  filter: grayscale(1%);
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: .4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  height: auto;
}

#panelLink h3 a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding: 20%;
  transition-property: padding;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#panelLink h3 a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#panelLink h3 a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="homePanel">
  <div id="panelLink">
    <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/"><img src="https://www.landscapia.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/landscapia-design.jpg" alt="Landscapia Design" width="600" height="600" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    <h3><a href="https://www.google.co.uk/">Design</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is the text link is wobbling / flickering when I hover the link. I'm guessing this is because the CSS is trying to also re-center the text to adjust for the extra padding, which is causing the flicker on the hover.

I've also included a link to CodePen showing the code in action - https://codepen.io/rolandxp30/pen/oNqZoom

I can't think of any other way of doing this? - is there a way of stabilising or centering the text or another way of creating the same animation effect?

Thanks in advance, kind regards

Brian

Comment: I'd use an absolute positioned pseudo element on the link for the background, and then simply apply a `transform: scale(5)` on hover.

Comment: Hi Gerard, apologies for the silly question, what is an absolute positioned pseudo element? - I've Googled it, but I'm none the wiser :( Is this something that replaces the current - position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); bit? Ideally I need this to be automatically adjusted for different resolutions, eg. as a percentage, rather than a specific amount - if that makes sense? - or is this not possible, I tried the transform: scale bit and that seemed to work as an alternative to the padding.

Comment: Apologies, thank you for your reply too! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an absolute positioned pseudo element on the link for the background, and then simply apply a `transform: scale(...)` on hover.

> what is an absolute positioned pseudo element?

A [pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements), that is absolutely positioned ;-)

Positioning it at top/right/bottom/left 0, makes it take the dimensions of the parent. And on hover, it simply gets scaled up. I used a factor of 3 here, that appears to be sufficient. You don't want to go too high here, otherwise there will be a noticeable delay before you see the it shrink again, when you un-hover the element.

```css
#homePanel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#homePanel img {
  width: 100%;
  filter: grayscale(1%);
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: .4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  height: auto;
}

#panelLink h3 a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 20%;
}

#panelLink h3 a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#panelLink h3 a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: .5s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#panelLink h3 a:hover::after {
  transform: scale(3);
}
```

```html
<div id="homePanel">
  <div id="panelLink">
    <a href="https://www.google.co.uk/"><img src="https://www.landscapia.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2022/03/landscapia-design.jpg" alt="Landscapia Design" width="600" height="600" class="img-responsive" /></a>
    <h3><a href="https://www.google.co.uk/">Design</a></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That absolutely nailed it! - thank you so much for your help! :)

Kind regards, Brian

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might works!

I just make a design label outside a because of padding. (Note: Please do additional change based on your requirement if required with anchor tag.)

This is html code.

```
<div id="homePanel">
<div id="panelLink">
<a href="https://www.google.co.uk/"><img 
 src="https://www.landscapia.co.uk/wp- 
 content/uploads/2022/03/landscapia-design.jpg" alt="Landscapia Design" 
 width="600" height="600" class="img-responsive" /></a>
<h3><span>Design</span><a href="https://www.google.co.uk/"></a></h3>
</div>
```

This is css code:

```
#homePanel {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 position: relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}

#homePanel img {
 width: 100%;
 filter: grayscale(1%);
 transition-property: opacity;
 transition-duration: .4s;
 transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
 height: auto;
} 

#panelLink h3 span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 color: #ffffff;
 z-index: 1;
}

#panelLink h3 a {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 font-weight: bold;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 padding: 20%;
 transition-property: padding;
 transition-duration: .5s;
 transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

#panelLink h3 a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

#panelLink h3 a:hover {
 padding: 100%;
}
```